# Mail is not sending if FromId is Gmailid

Tags: php, email, gmail

I am using php mail() for sending a 'contact us' mail.
The code is given below

```
$mailTo='test@example.com';
$mailfrom='test@gmail.com';
$mailSubject=$subject;
$mailBody="testing";
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$mailfrom."\n";
mail($mailTo,$mailSubject,$mailBody,$headers);
```

If From Id is a Gmail id Mail is not sending.Any Idea?

Comment: You must have ssl active. Set gmail host and port. Use gmail user name and password. Nothing doing this, you mail could only likely work with other servers but not gmail. That's because smtp server would be localhost which is not the case with gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Does it working with Yahoo or other email id,you can try by enabling SSL property set as true
set **smtpClientObj.EnableSsl = true**; in your code and try hope it helps you i was having a same problem in *C# code for PHP you can search how to set this EnableSSL property to True*

Comment: Where in the sample code do you see a `smtpClientObj`? Nowhere. That's the wrong language entirely.

Comment: @duskwuff sorry for my mistake i had posted a C# code instead of PHP for PHP you will have to set the EnableSSL property of the gmail server to True to enable sending mails

Answer (score 1):

Use gmail SSL to authenticate:

```
$from = "from.gmail.com";
$to = "to.yahoo.com";
$subject = "Test";
$body = "Test";

$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "asitha.gmail.com";
$password = "password";
```

Comment: and use PEAR Mail package.

Answer (score 0):

You are not Gmail. Do not send email pretending to be them.

(It's probably being blocked by a spam filter.)